# In R, how do I make flat slope graph/scatter graph with multiple values per row?

Tags: r, graph, visualization, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a chart that looks like this:

[image]

Except instead of the different media organisations on each row, you would have each individual survey participant (there are 47, I know this is could make for a messy chart), and then instead of "All", "Conservative" and "Labour" as the three data points on each row, it would be Survey1$Variable_X and Survey2$Variable_X. This would let me visualise the change and the magnitude of the change in this variable. Something that looks like this:

[image]

I did make this in a simple scatter graph just using the result of (Survey2$Variable_X - Survey1$Variable_X) but this just looks a bit boring, whereas the chart pictured above, to me, is far more interesting.

I know this is a version of a scatter chart, but does anyone have insight into how to make something like this in R, or can anyone tell me the specific name of this type of graph? I tried a slope graph but it was extremely messy:

[image]

Thank you in advance for any and all help :)

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to add some sample data, something like this:

```
  participantNum survey1_score survey2_score
1              1           -28             4
2              2           -14            16
3              3            20           -10
4              4             6             8
5              5           -20            26
6              6            22            24
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I find https://r-graph-gallery.com/ to be a great resource to find plots you want based on how they look and then see the code _and data_ used to create them.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: I have added some sample data now, I hope this helps. Sorry I meant to put it in my original post but forgot. Thank you everyone for the advice already :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame( participantNum = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                  survey1_score = c(-28, -14, 20, 6, -20, 22), 
                  survey2_score = c(4,16, -10, 8, 26,24)
)


ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x=factor(participantNum), xend=participantNum, y=survey1_score, yend=survey2_score), color="grey") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=participantNum, y=survey1_score), color=rgb(0.2,0.7,0.1,0.5), size=3 ) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=participantNum, y=survey2_score), color=rgb(0.7,0.2,0.1,0.5), size=3 ) +
  coord_flip()+
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
  )
```

[image: sample]

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much, perfect solution. Accepted as answer.